# Writing compatibility code for older versions of non-IE browsers

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, cross-browser

I was wondering if professional HTML/CSS/JS developers worry about compatibility with not the latest Firefox, Chrome or Opera? My experience with the browsers is that they just update automatically and there isn't REALLY a version system like for IE where you get major releases tied to new OS versions.

So do people worry about their code being compatible with an older Firefox version or do people just assume that if somebody's using their site that means they're connected to the internet thus they have the newest version of their non-IE browser if they choose to use one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you take a visit to http://caniuse.com/.

This site has very thorough browser support tables for versions of all common browsers, going back a pretty long way (certainly as far as anyone needs to worry about).

So that's the first thing CanIUse.com will do for you: It'll tell you for every major browser feature, what versions of which browsers support that feature. This can help you decide whether or not to use that feature in your site.

Secondly, they also have up-to-date browser usage statistics. This tells you for every version of every browser, what percentage of web users are using that particular browser/version. This can help you decide which browser versions to support. For example, if IE6 has 1% of the browser market, you may decide that's a small enough number of users to make the extra hassle of supporting it not worth the effort. The same will apply for other browsers.

More generally, of the major non IE browsers:

- Chrome has always has auto-update feature. Virtually everyone will be on the latest version, or at worst one version behind. Anyone using a version more than a couple of months old is an abberation.
- Firefox is now in the same position as Chrome for up-to-date users. However they also have a long-term support version (currently FFv10), which is not updated as often. You need to support this. In addition, users with version prior to their auto-update feature may not have upgraded. There are still a small but significant number of FF3.6 and FF4 users out there. Most other versions have pretty much faded away due to upgrades by now though.
- Opera is also pretty good at keeping itself up-to-date, and it seems that most Opera users are themselves quite mindful of this too, so you generally don't need to worry about old versions of Opera.
- Safari is the one where you might have to keep an eye on old versions. Safari has the problem that newer versions do not always support older hardware or operating systems, and therefore users with say a slightly out-of-date Macbook find that they can't upgrade to the latest Safari. There are therefore quite a number of versions of Safari still kicking around out there. But check the CanIUse stats for a clearer breakdown of the versions.

Comment: Very useful answer. Now i understand why there're a lot of FF4 and below users

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question. We DO worry about browser versions, but mostly IE. I don't know if it is safe to 'assume' current FireFox, Chrome, or Safari browsers, but maybe because the volume of traffic we get from those browsers is small enough that we just don't hear. Plus, I may be going out on a limb but they seem a bit less touchy rev-to-rev - more tolerant of standards-based layout. Hopefully, anyway.

Not sure if that answers your question, but what you describe is what we do, sort-of unintentionally :)

Answer (score 2):

The main reason i can think of, is that WindowsXP (~30% of worldwide users) doesn't support IE9, while Win7 (luckly) doesn't support IE8. And there's a big, big gap between the two.

Requirements for any version of FF, Chrome or Opera are: monitor, internet connection, electricity.

I keep an old laptop for tests, with Firefox 3, version 10<sup>something</sup> of Chrome and 3.1 of Safari. Guess what? They ***all*** support `border-radius`, `rgba`, `opacity`... At worst, you need vendor prefixes. Try to emulate `rgba` on text in IE8, you'll go nuts.

In short, only the latest features are left behind in older versions of non-IE browsers. And for those i already need a fallback for IE9, so...

If you code a website compatible with IE9, it will *probably* run well on older versions of other browsers. It runs on IE8 too? Bingo!

---

P.S. that's the first comment on Microsoft's [AlphaImageLoader Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969.aspx) specs:

> question to any microsoft support person why do you still offer a web
>   browser if its complete (censored)? learn to update faster i mean jesus why
>   is it taking so long to be full compliant with html5 what do you have
>   5 coders?

And it's dated...nine september twothousandand **TEN**.

Answer (score 0):

I run a content oriented website where my charts and diagrams are king.

I make my website look pretty on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.  I make sure it looks well enough on IE 7 and 8.  For IE6, all I care is that someone can /use/ it.

Answer (score 0):

No. No one cares about older non-ie browsers, unless it's some terrible enterprise thing where you have to support a client because their tech supoort is tied to Firefox 2.

You should not care either unless you have a very specific reason to.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to vary depending on your target market. General advice can't substitute for specific knowledge here. If you run a public site, look at your access logs or analytics to see what browser versions are actually connecting. If you distribute an on-premise application you'll need to survey your customers, which is a bit harder. I'm assuming that you're not doing internal development, since then your IT department should be able to tell you exactly what versions to expect.

I work on an on-premise enterprise web application. For IE we target 8, 9, and 10. We can get away with not supporting 6 and 7 because they can be upgraded to 8 on all versions of Windows. For Firefox we test with the latest mainline and [enterprise support](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) releases. Our customers hardly use Chrome and Safari at all, so we only test the latest mainline release of each.

Browsers other than IE tend to be more tolerant of new markup, even in older versions. The biggest thing to watch out for is vendor prefixes on CSS properties. Even if the current version uses the standard property, you can get support for older versions trivially be adding the prefixed one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing most of my development in Chrome beta, and a few months ago my manager tried my page in Chrome 19 while I was on 20, and she ran into a problem because I was tickling a bug in the older version. At that time I got an account at BrowserStack.